# Angular Data table sorting works only on 1 column?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Sorting works on column Id but it doesn't work on the second column, why so?

```
<mat-table #detailsTable #detailsSort="matSort" [dataSource]="details" matSort>

<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Id </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let detail"> {{detail.id}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="invoiceCurrencyNetValue">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Net value </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let detail"> {{detail.attributes.invoiceCurrencyNetValue}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="this.detailsColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: this.detailsColumns;" matRipple class="element-row"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

And this is how I set the data and sort in `.ts` file:

```
details = new MatTableDataSource(details.data);
details.sort = this.detailsSort;
```

And this is columns declaration:

```
detailsColumns = [
    'id', 'invoiceCurrencyNetValue'
];
```

Comment: how does your `detailsColumns` look like? It should use the same id as `invoiceCurrencyNetValue` I guess.

Comment: it does, i have edited question

Comment: Have a look at [official document](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably because your `attributes` is an object, and the sorting is expecting an actual value.

e.g. detail.id can be sorted by id value, but detail.attributes.invoiceCurrencyNetValue cannot be sorted, as it is an object, not an actual value.

You can start from here: [Angular Material 2 DataTable Sorting with nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891174/angular-material-2-datatable-sorting-with-nested-objects)

As a reference, you can extend your sort functionality by using "`sortingDataAccessor`"