# sorting not working properly in angular material-table

Tags: javascript, sorting, angular9, angular-material-table

I have a user table where sorting is not working properly for the role column.

The data that I get from the service `getAllUsers` is like this :
[image: Reponse Image]

Here is the HTML code:
it is a very long code that is why at first i thought i must put the needed block only.

```
    <div class="page-layout simple">
  <div class="w-100-p">
    <div
      class="header accent p-24"
      fxLayout="column"
      fxLayoutAlign="center
            center"
      fxLayout.gt-sm="row"
      fxLayoutAlign.gt-sm="space-between center"
    >
      <div class="logo" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
        <span class="logo-text h1">Users</span>
      </div>

      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center">
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="ExportAll()" matTooltip="Export Excel">
          <mat-icon class="secondary-text">cloud_download</mat-icon>
        </button>


        <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="goToCreateUser()">
          Add User
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-card p-24">
      <div>
        <mat-table class="p-8" #table matSort [dataSource]="userDataSource">
          <ng-container matColumnDef="UserName">
            <mat-header-cell
              mat-sort-header
              fxLayoutAlign="center center"
              *matHeaderCellDef
              >Uid</mat-header-cell
            >
            <mat-cell fxLayoutAlign="center center" *matCellDef="let user">
              <p class="text-truncate">{{ user.UserName }}</p>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="FirstName">
            <mat-header-cell
              mat-sort-header
              fxLayoutAlign="center center"
              *matHeaderCellDef
              >Name</mat-header-cell
            >
            <mat-cell fxLayoutAlign="center center" *matCellDef="let user">
              <p class="text-truncate">
                {{ user.FirstName }} {{ user.LastName }}
              </p>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="PhoneNumber">
            <mat-header-cell
              mat-sort-header
              fxLayoutAlign="center center"
              *matHeaderCellDef
              >Phone Number</mat-header-cell
            >
            <mat-cell fxLayoutAlign="center center" *matCellDef="let user">
              <p
                class="job-title text-truncate"
                *ngIf="user.PhoneNumber; else noData"
              >
                {{ user.PhoneNumber }}
              </p>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="Role.Name">
            <mat-header-cell
              mat-sort-header
              fxLayoutAlign="center center"
              *matHeaderCellDef
              >Role</mat-header-cell
            >
            <mat-cell fxLayoutAlign="center center" *matCellDef="let user">
              <p class="job-title text-truncate" *ngIf="user.Role; else noData">
                {{ user.Role.Name }}
              </p>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="Department">
            <mat-header-cell
              mat-sort-header
              fxLayoutAlign="center center"
              *matHeaderCellDef
              >Team</mat-header-cell
            >
            <mat-cell fxLayoutAlign="center center" *matCellDef="let user">
              <p
                class="job-title text-truncate"
                *ngIf="user.Department; else noData"
              >
                {{ user.Department }}
              </p>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="ActiveOnLdap">
            <mat-header-cell
              mat-sort-header
              fxLayoutAlign="center center"
              *matHeaderCellDef
              >Status on LDAP</mat-header-cell
            >
            <mat-cell fxLayoutAlign="center center" *matCellDef="let user">
              <div
                [ngClass]="
                  user.ActiveOnLDAP ? 'tag-color-valid' : 'tag-color-invalid'
                "
                [matTooltip]="user.ActiveOnLDAP ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'"
              ></div>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container
            (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
            matColumnDef="actions"
          >
            <mat-header-cell fxLayoutAlign="center center" *matHeaderCellDef
              >Actions</mat-header-cell
            >
            <mat-cell fxLayoutAlign="center center" *matCellDef="let user">
              <button
                mat-icon-button
                (click)="goToEdit(user.Id)"
                matTooltip="Edit"
              >
                <mat-icon class="secondary-text">open_in_new</mat-icon>
              </button>
              <button
                *ngIf="user.LockoutEnabled"
                mat-icon-button
                matTooltip="Activate"
                (click)="ActivateUser(user.UserName)"
              >
                <mat-icon class="secondary-text">lock_open</mat-icon>
              </button>

              <button
                *ngIf="!user.LockoutEnabled"
                mat-icon-button
                matTooltip="Deactivate"
                (click)="DesactivateUser(user.UserName)"
              >
                <mat-icon class="secondary-text">lock</mat-icon>
              </button>
              <button
                mat-icon-button
                matTooltip="Delete"
                (click)="deleteUser(user)"
              >
                <mat-icon class="secondary-text">delete</mat-icon>
              </button>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
          <mat-header-row
            *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"
          ></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let user; columns: displayedColumns"> </mat-row>
        </mat-table>
        <mat-paginator
          #paginator
          [length]="userDataSource.data.length"
          [pageIndex]="0"
          [pageSize]="5"
          [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
        >
        </mat-paginator>

        <ng-template #noData>
          <p>N/A</p>
        </ng-template>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the user model :

```
    export class userModel {
  FirstName: string;
  LastName: string;
  Email: string;
  Deleted: Delete;
  PhoneNumber: string;
  Uid: string;
  Department: string;
  ActiveONldap: boolean;
  Role: any[];
  Avatar = [];
  ConfirmPassword;
  Password;
  UserName: string;

  constructor(user?) {
    user = user || {};
    this.FirstName = user.firstName || "";
    this.Deleted = user.Deleted || Delete.UNDELETED;
    this.UserName = user.userName || "";
    this.LastName = user.lastName || "";
    this.PhoneNumber = user.phoneNumber || "";
    this.Email = user.email || "";
    this.Uid = user.uid || "";
    this.Role = user.Role || [];
    this.ActiveONldap = user.activeONldap;
    this.Department = user.department || "";
    this.ConfirmPassword = user.confirmPassword || "";
    this.Password = user.password || "";
  }
}

export interface CurrentUser {
  Avatar: any;
  Email: string;
  FirstName: string;
  HasRegistered: boolean;
  LastName: string;
  LoginProvider: any;
  Role: string;
  UserName: string;
}

export enum RoleIds {
  Administrator = "1",
  Manager = "2",
  Recruiter = "3",
  Interviewer = "4",
  Requester = "5",
  Viewer = "6",
}

export enum Roles {
  Administrator = "Administrator",
  Manager = "Manager",
  Recruiter = "Recruiter",
  Interviewer = "Interviewer",
  Requester = "Requester",
  Viewer = "Viewer",
}

export class RoleModel {
  Id: string;
  Name: string;

  constructor(role?) {
    role = role || {};
    this.Id = role.Id || "0000000001";
    this.Name = role.Name || "";
  }
}
```

this is the TS code :

```
reloadData() {
    this.usersService.getAllIUsers().subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        if (res) {
          this.userList = res.accountsList;
          this.userDataSource.data = this.userList;
          this.userDataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item: any, property: string): any => {
            switch (property) {
              case 'Role.Name': return item.Role.Name;
              default: return item[property]?.toString().toLowerCase() || "Ω";
            }
          };
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        this.snotify.error("Error loading users");
      }
    );
  }
```

Here is the erreur in the browser console that i get when i try to do role sort (the others work fine)

[Sort Error for Role Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMLgq.png)

Here is the userService :

```
    export class usersService {
  private readonly usersUrl = environment.apiEndpoint + "Account";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAllIUsers(): Observable<userModel> {
    return this.http.get<userModel>(this.usersUrl + "/accountsList");
  }
}
```

PS : I tried both Role: any[] and Role: RoleModel[] in user Model neither one of them worked.

What's wrong?

I am using Angular 9.

Comment: Please post all code in plain-text using proper formatting (e.g. fenced code blocks) instead images. So we can reproduce. Add a [example] and do research, e.g. [Angular mat-sort not working on matColumnDef with dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184169/angular-mat-sort-not-working-on-matcolumndef-with-dot-notation).

Comment: Sorry i'm new here so how i do that ?

Comment: when i added case 'Role.Name': return item.Role.Name; i get this error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'Name')
    at userDataSource.sortingDataAccessor

Comment: Please send the code as code-blocks. We can't help with the code as images as it can be hard to read, and we cannot easily diagnose the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok i'll send it in 2 hours

Comment: The code edit is done i've put the html + user model code

Comment: your model says the role is an array but your JSON says your role is the object. how and where you are mapping it?

Comment: I need more explications to the mapping because i'm new to the project and angular

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me please ?