# material sort not working on some columns

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material, mat-table

I'm implementing the sortModule for angular material mat-table but for some reason it works perfectly for all the columns expect one. When I try to sort with it returns the table to it's initial situation but it does not sort.

html code for the mat-table:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="demandesData" matSort matSortActive="dateCreation" matSortDirection="desc" >
```

columns that work:

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="typeDemande" >
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header >
          Type demande 
        </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
           {{ element.typeDemande }} 
        </mat-cell>

 </ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="dateCreation">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> date création </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
           {{ convertDate(element.dateCreation) }} 
        </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

the sorting is not working on this column:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="nom">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Nom du collaborateur</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
           {{ element.user_ajout.nom }} 
        </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

the data in the table:
[image]

Comment: I think it is working as intended, right now you are sorting based on data. When you will sort based upon the column specified by you, then in ascending order Uppercase values will come first and then lowercase and in descending vice versa.

Comment: in the image it's sorted by the third column, but when I try the second it does not work

Comment: please create stackblitz

Answer (score 3):

The columns that sort are simple properties that are direct children of the data row: `dateCreation` and `typeDemand`. They are also specified in their respective `matColumnDef` attribute. The middle column is a property inside the object `user_ajout` and not matching the `matColumnDef` attribute. Such "deep" values don't sort by the default comparator but need their custom sort comparator. This is called `sortingDataAccessor`.

Comment: Good example in the first answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48891174/angular-material-2-datatable-sorting-with-nested-objects