# Set the MatCellDef iterator for a specific JSON such that the matsort and matsearch work in a matTable

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-datatables, angular-material-table

So I have a JSON Of the following Format:

```
        {
            "loan": {
                "loanKey": 6575,
                "poolNum": "300801056",
                "triggers": [
                    {
                        "id": 4276,
                        "triggerType": "DSCR",
                        "triggerValue": 1.2
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "loan": {
                "loanKey": 6651,
                "poolNum": "30308716"
            }
        },
        {
            "loan": {
                "loanKey": 8224,
                "poolNum": "998"
            }
        },
        {
            "loan": {
                "loanKey": 8225,
                "poolNum": "999"
            }
        },
        {
            "loan": {
                "loanKey": 9877,
                "poolNum": "998"
            }
        },
        {
            "loan": {
                "loanKey": 9878,
                "poolNum": "999"
            }
        }
]
```

Now I am accessing a certain row and its internal elements in a way below:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="loanKey">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Loan Key/ID</th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
         {{ row.loan.loanKey }}
         </td>
</ng-container>
```

With this I am getting the value I req. to display on the table, but due to mismatch of the matColumnDef name and interpolation name the matSearch and Sort arent working. Can anyone help fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1: Without `MatTableDataSource`**

From [MatTable Sorting section](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting),

> If you are not using the MatTableDataSource, but instead implementing custom logic to sort your data, listen to the sort's (matSortChange) event and re-order your data according to the sort state. If you are providing a data array directly to the table, don't forget to call renderRows() on the table, since it will not automatically check the array for changes.

1. Trigger `sortChange($event)` function when `matSortChange` event is fired.

```
<table
  mat-table
  [dataSource]="data"
  class="mat-elevation-z8"
  matSort
  (matSortChange)="sortChange($event)"
>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="loanKey">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Loan Key/ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      {{ row.loan.loanKey }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

2. Define a dictionary with the column name, the sorting direction, and its sorting logic.
3. In `sortChange` function, sort the data by getting the sorting implementation by `sort.active` (column name) and `sort.direction` (sort direction) from `sortDict`. And also execute `table.renderChanges()` so that the MatTable will reflect the changes.

```js
@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<Model>;

sortDict = {
  loanKey: {
    asc: (a: Model, b: Model) => a.loan.loanKey - b.loan.loanKey,
    desc: (a: Model, b: Model) => b.loan.loanKey - a.loan.loanKey,
  },
};

sortChange(sortState: Sort) {
  this.data.sort(this.sortDict[sortState.active][sortState.direction]);

  this.table.renderRows();
}
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hntgf7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

**Solution 2: With `MatTableDataSource`**

From [MatTable Sorting section](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting),

> Note that if the data properties do not match the column names, or if a more complex data property accessor is required, then a custom sortingDataAccessor function can be set to override the default data accessor on the MatTableDataSource.

Credit to the [answer from @Steve Sanders' on Angular Material 2 DataTable Sorting with nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49057493/8017690).

Concern from his answer is that you need to override the `sortingDataAccessor` and `sort` from the `dataSource` in `AfterViewInit` lifecycle.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="loanKey">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Loan Key/ID</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      {{ row.loan.loanKey }}
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

```js
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Model>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.data);
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
    switch (property) {
      case 'loanKey':
        return item.loan.loanKey;
      default:
        return item[property];
    }
  };
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q2nvlk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the solutions worked, there are type mismatches and Sort undefined messages.

Comment: Can you create your current code in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com) for a reproducible example?

Comment: there was a minor reference error, the second method worked.thnx.