# How to understand syntax in TypeScript interface [key: string]

Tags: typescript

I'm having trouble deciphering a TypeScript syntax I found within an interface declaration here.

```
interface FormattingOptions {
    tabSize: number;
    insertSpaces: boolean;
    [key: string]: boolean | number | string;
}
```

Can someone explain me the third parameter of this interface? The one containing `[key: string] ...`? How is this type of syntax called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: bracket notation property access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727936/typescript-bracket-notation-property-access)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's an [index signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures). It means that besides the known properties of the interface, any other properties of type `boolean`, `number` or `string` can be present

```
interface FormattingOptions {
    tabSize: number;
    insertSpaces: boolean;
    [key: string]: boolean | number | string;
}

let f: FormattingOptions = {
  tabSize: 1,
  insertSpaces: true,
  other: '' // witout the  index signature this would be invalid.
};
```

Comment: Does this mean that I can add as many new properties as I wish? Could I also add `mouse: 'tippy'` and `car: 'BMW'` and still have the variable `f` in this example be valid?

Comment: @Socrates Yup, as long as the extra properties are of type boolean, number or string .