# How to Pass Key value from inputText change in ReactJs in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-dom

I am using switch case for comparison for object key with string in below code:

```
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { Component, ReactNode } from "react";

import classes from "./Contact.module.scss";

class contactForm extends Component {
    state = {
        contactForm: {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            message: "",
            phone: ""
        }
    };

    render(): ReactNode {
        return (
            <form className={classes.ArticleBody}>
                <div className={classes.ContactForm}>
                    <TextField
                        value={this.state.contactForm.name}
                        onChange={event => this._inputChangeHandler(event, "name")}
                        label="Full Name"
                        required
                    />
                    <TextField
                        value={this.state.contactForm.email}
                        onChange={event => this._inputChangeHandler(event, "email")}
                        type="Email"
                        label="Email"
                        required
                    />
                    <TextField
                        value={this.state.contactForm.phone}
                        onChange={event => this._inputChangeHandler(event, "phone")}
                        type="phone"
                        label="Phone Number"
                        required
                    />
                    <TextField
                        type="textarea"
                        value={this.state.contactForm.message}
                        label="Comment/Message"
                        rows="4"
                        onChange={event => this._inputChangeHandler(event, "message")}
                        multiline
                        required
                    />
                </div>

                <div className={classes.Submit}>
                    <Button type="submit" onClick={this._submitContactForm}>
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }

    private _inputChangeHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, key: string) => {
        const updatedFormData = { ...this.state.contactForm };
        switch (key) {
            case "email":
                updatedFormData.email = event.target.value;
                break;
            case "phone":
                updatedFormData.phone = event.target.value;
                break;
            case "message":
                updatedFormData.message = event.target.value;
                break;
            case "name":
                updatedFormData.name = event.target.value;
                break;
        }
        this.setState({ contactForm: updatedFormData });
    };

    private _submitContactForm = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>): void => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.contactForm);
    };
}

export default contactForm;
```

I don't want to compare my object keys with `switch` case. Is there any generic approach for changing values on input change for the defined state?
e.g.: in below code I am trying to match key from parameter in method `_inputChangeHandler` but it throws error

> *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string' can't be used to index type '{ name: string; email: string;
>   message: string; phone: string; }'*

```
const updatedFormData = { ...this.state.contactForm };
updatedFormData[key] = event.target.value;
this.setState({ contactForm: updatedFormData });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this

```
this.setState({ contactForm: {...this.state.contactForm, [key]: event.target.value} });
```

@Ajay Verma

you could set the `name` attribute of the `TextField` and then you can get the key from the `event`.

**like this**

```
...
private _inputChangeHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const key = event.target.name;
...
<TextField
    value={this.state.contactForm.phone}
    name="phone"
    onChange={this._inputChangeHandler}
    type="phone"
    label="Phone Number"
    required
/>
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't want to open another question but Can I use something generic for harcoded key value in onChange method: `onChange={event => this._inputChangeHandler(event, "name")}`  here "name" is hardcoded.

Answer (score 2):

The [TextField](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props) has a name prop.

> When you need to handle multiple controlled input elements, you can
>   add a name attribute to each element and let the handler function
>   choose what to do based on the value of event.target.name. [React
>   Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs)

For example:

```
<TextField
  name="name"
  value={this.state.contactForm.name}
  onChange={this._inputChangeHandler}
  label="Full Name"
  required
/>

....

public _inputChangeHandler(e) {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    return {
      contactForm: { 
        ...prevState.contactForm,     
        [e.target.name] : e.target.value
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: okay.. thank you.. that'll remove my extra parameter from method. Thank you for the links

Answer (score 1):

A general inputChangeHandler can be:

```
private _inputChangeHandler = (
  event: React.ChangeEvent<
    HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement
  >,
  key: string
) => {
  this.setState({
    contactForm: {
      ...this.state.contactForm,
      [key]: event.target.value,
    },
  });
};
```

Your original code would work but you have to give [typescript a hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55108590/1641941) when using bracket notation to access a property:

```
const contactForm: {
  [key: string]: string;
} = {
  ...this.state.contactForm,
};
contactForm[key] = event.target.value;

this.setState({
  contactForm,
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response too. It is same as marked answer and both works perfectly. :)

Comment: @AjayVerma It probably is type inference problem, if you define a type for conatactForm your code would probably work as well.

Comment: Okay.. I didn't know that thank you for suggestion I'll definitely try to do that 
also, I don't want to open another question but Can I use something generic for harcoded key value in onChange method: `onChange={event => this._inputChangeHandler(event, "name")}` here "name" is hardcoded.

Comment: @AjayVerma Updated my answer, your code would have worked if you give typescript a hint to be ok with bracket notation (`object[key]`)

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try and will also look into the interface problem that you mentioned earlier. Thank you for your help. I am learning React, so sorry if I seem confused.

Comment: @AjayVerma instead of passing the string "name" you can give the input a property called "name": `name="name" onChange={this._inputChangeHandler}` and in your handler start with: `const key = event.target.name;`